# Extract a phone number from a web page then do something with it

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to know the quickest and easiest way to get a phone number from the current webpage and send it directly via Whatsapp (WebWhatsapp wa.me/...), or just get the number by an alert box, thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        name: "Ad phone number displayed",
        type: "Show",
        action: "Click",
        object: {
          type: "PhoneContact",
          id: "37440633",
          telephone: "0666666666",
          inReplyTo: {
            id: "37440633",
            adId: 37440633,
            contentId: 37440633,
            type: "ClassifiedAd",
            name: "Seph",
            phone: "0666666666",
            price: Number(price), 

</script>
```

what i want:

> https://wa.me/00330666666666

Answer (score 2):

you can create a regular expression in order to just extract the numbers after
the word "telephone", or just create a regular expression that extracts the sequence of numbers in each line. I hope this helps you. Any doubt you can ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these npm packages

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/phone-number-extractor`

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio`

with this [chrome extension boilerplate](https://github.com/fxnoob/chrome-extension-boilerplate)